# Desktop PC and Android interface

Tags: android, interface, desktop

I'm thinking to develop a PC desktop program to get application setting from android phone, install/uninstall apk application, sync photos/videos/music and display a web content.

Initial thought is to use .Net to write desktop program and shell ADB tool to do installation and file copy on android phone. However seems like advanced feature of ADB only works on a rooted android phone.

Is there an communication interface between windows and android system? Based on an app called "Android Manager" by Mobile Action, it seems that it can pull out what apps are installed on the phone but seems like this cannot be done by ADB alone without root access.

I would like to do the transfer of information using USB cable. Any thoughts where to research on? Thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the USB cable you can only use ADB, but you can use ADB to set up a socket between your pc and the mobile device. Both sides can then connect to this socket and use it to transmit data.